# React Native / Victory Charts : Need to style coords

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, victory-charts

I am building a small mobile app in React Native that displays a line graph.

I have built the line graph via Victory Charts component.

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { VictoryBar, VictoryChart, VictoryAxis, VictoryLine } from 'victory-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <VictoryChart
          domainPadding={{x: 40}}
          style={{marginLeft: 120}}
        >
          <VictoryLine
            data={[
              {logdate: "11-01", temp: 110 },
              {logdate: "12-01", temp: 98 },



            ]}
            x="logdate"
            y="temp"
            style={{
              data: {opacity: 0.7},
              labels: {fontSize: 12},
              parent: {border: "1px dotted #001"}
            }}

          />
          <VictoryAxis
            label="logdate"
            style={{
              axisLabel: { padding: 30 }
            }}
          />
          <VictoryAxis dependentAxis
            label="temp"
            style={{
              axisLabel: { padding: 40 }
            }}
          />
      </VictoryChart>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

The line graph is displayed as shown below [image]

The graph is working fine.

I need help in styling of the x-axis co-ord's label as highlighted in the pic.

Instead of showing "11-01" horizontally I want it to be shown vertically as shown in the pic.

Anyone has any ideas ?

Comment: hello Aaron! probably the best place to post this question is in the issues for victory-native, at: https://github.com/formidableLabs/victory-native.

I can't personally help you with this, just thought I'd let you know that you might get more success from looking in the issues there, good luck!

Comment: How to Change the graph color?

Answer (score 0):

Add tickLabels: { angle: -90, }
in style of VictoryAxis :

```
      <VictoryAxis
        label="logdate"
        style={{
          axisLabel: { padding: 30 },
          tickLabels: { angle: -90, }
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just add two victory Axis before the victory line

add *dependentAxis* for the first

```
<VictoryAxis dependentAxis />
```

for the second add the axeY list to the *ticketFormat* item and define the -60 angle style.

```
<VictoryAxis 
   style={{ tickLabels: { angle: -60 } }}
   tickFormat={AxeY}
/>
```

Hopefully I help you